# Upload to OneDrive via BITS

Tags: powershell, file-upload, onedrive, powershell-4.0, microsoft-bits

I'm trying to submit a file to OneDrive using BITS.
I found an article on this here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn858877.aspx; but I was hoping PowerShell's native `Start-BitsTransfer` method could save me some effort.  However that article implies that OneDrive supports BITS uploads; so things are promising.

```powershell
$source = '\\myFileServer\Backups\SqlServerDbBackup.bak' #3.2GB file
$destination = 'https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/personal/my_account/Documents/SqlServerDbBackup.bak'
$cred = get-credential #here I enter the same credentials I use to access the site
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $source -Destination $destination -TransferType Upload -Credential $cred
```

When I run the above code the progress bar briefly pops up, then an error appears.  Full output (including credentials prompt) below:

```
cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Start-BitsTransfer : HTTP status 501: The server does not support the functionality required to fulfill the request.
At line:8 char:1
+ Start-BitsTransfer -Source $source -Destination $destination -TransferType Uploa ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-BitsTransfer], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartBitsTransferCOMException,Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.NewBitsTransferCommand
```

Has anyone attempted this before / any ideas whether it's possible to perform an upload to OneDrive using `start-bitstransfer`?

Comment: if you enter creds manually like `Start-BitsTransfer -Credential user@domain.com` you should be prompted for password, after that do you get the same error?

Comment: @Avshalom Yes, sadly passing a credentials variable or getting the `Start-BitsTransfer` commandlet to prompt for password results in the same outcome.

Comment: @JohnLBevan I don't think it's going to work, OneDrive expects an OAuth bearer token, an authentication scheme not supported by `Start-BitsTransfer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to upload to OneDrive for Business. The MSDN article you found applies to personal OneDrives; BITS isn't supported in OneDrive for Business. Although you can't use Start-BitsTransfer, you can find info about the new upload API's [here](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_large_files.htm), which work for both personal and business OneDrives.